# Error code full_adder.vhd(18): near ")": (vcom-1576) expecting IDENTIFIER

Tags: modelsim

I have this error code

```
full_adder.vhd(18): near ")": (vcom-1576) expecting IDENTIFIER.
```

I have tried the following and the error still occurs, does anyone have an idea?

```
LIBRARY IEEE;

USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;




USE IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;




ENTITY full_adder IS
  PORT (




a_i: in std_logic;



b_i: in std_logic;




c_i: in std_logic;




s_o: out std_logic;




c_o: out std_logic;




);




END full_adder;




ARCHITECTURE calcul OF full_adder IS




signal full_adder: std_logic;




BEGIN



 s_o <= c_i xor a_i xor b_i;




c_o <= c_i and(a_i xor b_i) or (a_i and b_i);



END calcul;
```

Answer (score 0):

The last item in your ports should not have a ';'. The ';' for that port is the one after the close bracket ');'.

```
port (
  a_i: in std_logic;
  ...
  s_o: out std_logic;
  c_o: out std_logic   -- Do not need ';' here 
);                     -- It is here
```